# SQL join in CodeIgniter with Active Record

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to wrap my head around this, but I seem to go in circles. I'm trying to list a users topics one by one, with the quotes belonging to that specific topic underneath. If that makes sense.

I have 3 tables, like so:

> [USERS] user_id username
>
> [TOPICS] topic_id user_id topic_name
>
> [QUOTES] quote_id topic_id quote_name

I want to be able to do something like this in my view:

> Username: Thomas
>
> > Topic 1: Whatever
> >
> > Quotes: One quote, another quote, and a third quote, all belonging to Topic 1.
> >
> > Topic 2: Another topic from Thomas
> >
> > Quotes: Yes indeed, Okay thanks, I love Stack Overflow, These quotes belong to Topic 2.

But I can't get it to work, I've been trying everything, including weird stuff like:

```
public function get_quotes()
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('topics');
    $this->db->join('quotes', 'topic_id = quote_id');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Is this strange, should I instead try using 'where' instead? Something like:

```
$this->db->where('user', $user_id);
$this->db->where('topic', $topic_id);
$this->db->where('quote', $quote_id);
```

I really appreciate any help I can get, or just a finger pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right off the bat I would ask **"What is not working?"**, secondly I would suggest you run the profiler to show you the **EXACT SQL** being generated, so that you can make a valid assessment of where the **ACTIVE QUERY** is failing you.

To use the profiler, stick this into your controller:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

It will result in a nice output of all DB calls, all POST vars, etc;
Reference here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html

**UPDATE**

So to fully do what you want, you need a query that returns the following columns:

```
user_id, username, topic_id, topic_name, quote_id, quote_name
```

Here is the active query you want (you can also use method chaining if that is clear enough):

```
$this->db->select('u.user_id, u.username, t.topic_id, t.topic_name, q.quote_id, q.quote_name');
$this->db->from('users u');
$this->db->join('topics t', 't.user_id = u.user_id'); // this joins the user table to topics
$this->db->join('quotes q', 'q.topic_id = t.topic_id'); // this joins the quote table to the topics table
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Your result set will then be something like:

```
user_id     | username  | topic_id  | topic_name    | quote_id  | quote_name
1           |Thomas     |1          |Whatever       |1          |One quote, anot...
2           |Ryan       |4          |Another...     |6          |To be or not to...
```

Once you have that result set, simply loop through the data to output it, and check to see if you have multiple quotes from the same person (say sort by user_id and do a test on the 2nd loop if its the same person, otherwise output the new users name).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Jakub, could you take a look at the comments beneath? I can't get an eye closed tonight before I fix this :)

Comment: I updated my answer with an active query that will work for you.

Comment: @Jakub, it looks pretty brilliant, thank you for helping me out. But I'm getting this error: `Unknown column 't.quote_id' in 'on clause'` I'm so lost in this SQL hell, but I feel like its right in front of my nose. To make it clear, here is my tables and columns: [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/FSNDShWK) Can you spot my failure?

Comment: @nielsiano, sorry I made a mistake, I have corrected the active query, it should have been `$this->db->join('quotes q', 'q.topic_id = t.topic_id');` I had quote_id before, hence your error

Comment: My added comment is that, lately I've been using joins in CodeIgniter, but using the above original question as an example, my query results in a data set that includes multiple occurrences of the same row, when Table-2 has multiple records associated with a row from Table-1. For example, there is one user from Table-1. But that one user has two rows of quotes in Table-2. The above query returns two rows of the same user. The only thing different are the values for the quotes. So I end up looping over the same data, twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of the quotes for a specific user:

```
$this->db->join('TOPICS t', 'u.user_id on t.user_id')
         ->join('QUOTES q', 't.topic_id on q.topic_id')
         ->where('u.user_id', $userId)
         ->get('USERS u');

// I always echo my queries when developing to make sure they are what i'm expecting
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

If you want all of the quotes for all of the users

```
$this->db->join('TOPICS t', 'u.user_id on t.user_id')
         ->join('QUOTES q', 't.topic_id on q.topic_id')
         ->get('USERS u');

echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Comment: Tried the first query, but I ended up with this error: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`on` t.user_id JOIN `QUOTES` q ON `t`.`topic_id` `on` q.topic_id WHERE `u`.`user' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`USERS` u) JOIN `TOPICS` t ON `u`.`user_id` `on` t.user_id JOIN `QUOTES` q ON `t`.`topic_id` `on` q.topic_id WHERE `u`.`user_id` = 1

Comment: can you post the query that got echoed out?

Comment: I fixed it by doing 'u.user_id = t.user_id' instead of on.