# Multiple join and update codeigniter sql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to make a query on CodeIgniter model, but when i make a multiple join with update it doesn't work. I have more tables to join I cant move on with these 3 tables only.

```
$emp_datas = array(
    'status' => 'test',
    'ticket_type' => 'SB',
);


$this->db->join('ticket_requests_type', 'ticket_requests_type.ticket_type_number = ticket_requests.ticket_type')    
->join('employee', 'employee.empe_id = ticket_requests.employee_involved')

->set($emp_datas)
->where('ticket_number', $ticket_no)
->update('ticket_requests_type','ticket_requests');
```

Comment: As far as I know Active Record doesn't support this yet.  You have to build a custom pure SQL query or use a ugly workaround like provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578253/codeigniter-active-record-update-statement-with-a-join

Comment: @vincent villafuerte Please [visit here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333392/sql-join-in-codeigniter-with-active-record?rq=1) i think you got your answer here

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear... The `UPDATE` clause can refer to a table alias specified in the `FROM` clause.

I am giving a Generic example here:

```
UPDATE A
SET foo = B.bar
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
    ON A.col1 = B.colx
WHERE ...
```